# memcpy() from smaller array to larger one

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

I couldn't find any reference to this question.
I have an array of structs which I need to resize into a larger array.
both structs are completely initialized (each cell has a value other than NULL)

say

```
typedef struct Square {
...
...
}Square;

Square s1[1024];
Square s2[2048];
```

If I copy using `memcpy()` s1 into s2, how would s2 would look? I know it copies byte data.
will the first 1024 cells would be the same as s1 and the remaining 1024 would be as they initialized? or does it affect them too?

Thanks

P.S The arrays here are statically allocated, but I wrote that just for convinience here. I have them allocated using `malloc()`

Comment: What do you mean by "each cell has a value other than NULL"? There are no pointers in the code you've shown us.

Comment: I wrote in the P.s, that it's declared here statically only for convinience. they actually defined as Square **s1 and later malloced

Comment: If you're really manipulating pointers to pointers, then you should show us code that manipulates pointers to pointers. There's a *lot* of confusion about the relationship between arrays and pointers, and you could easily be getting answers to the wrong question. Suggested reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www-c-faq.com).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you did:

```
memcpy(s2, s1, sizeof(s1));
```

The first 1024 `Square`s in `s2` would be copied from `s1`, and the rest would be untouched (so if they were uninitialized, they'll still be uninitialized).

Remember that if they're heap allocated as you say, you can't use `sizeof`.  You might find [realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) useful if all you're trying to do is grow the array.

Comment: That's what I did (the sizeof is calculated using a certain var*sizeof(int)
If it's a two dimension array, defined as Square **squares; should I pass to the function &squares, or just squares? compiler doesn't complain about both, and this whole multidimensional array using pointer is confusing

Comment: Hmm - a two-dimensional array is a whole different problem being an array of pointers, and probably warrants a new question.

Comment: It's not an array of pointers. it's an array of the struct Square, defined dynamically Square **squares. Perhaps I don't understand correctly, and it is an array of pointers. in that case, I'll post a new question

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: An array of pointers can be used to emulate a 2D array, but a 2D array is not an array of pointers; it's simply an array of arrays.

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't know, I'd argue it's an array of pointers to the first element of each array.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: No, a C two-dimensional array is an array of arrays. See 6.5.2.1 paragraph 3 of the latest [C standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), and section 6 of the [http://www.c-faq.com/](comp.lang.c FAQ). There's a common misconception that arrays and pointers are the same thing; they really really aren't. (As I said, an array of pointers can be used to emulate a data structure that acts like a 2D array.)

Comment: I wrote a new question, hopefully to explain better. though this question was helpful two.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787286/copying-multidimensional-array-pointers