# copying multidimensional array (pointers)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have two  structs pointers to pointers

```
typedef struct Square {
...
...
}Square;

Square **s1; //Representing 2D array of say, 100*100
Square **s2; //Representing 2D array of say, 200*200
```

Both are allocated on the heap using `malloc()`.
I have `s1` initialized with certain values and `s2` initialized completely with the default values.
Basically I need to resize `s1` to the size of `s2` while maintaining its (`s1`) values, and the 'added' values would be just as they were in `s2` - the default value.

I wrote this question [memcpy() from smaller array to larger one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786970/memcpy-from-smaller-array-to-larger-one/11786985) but apparently I'm confusing between arrays and pointers/

My question is, how to implement this resizing of `s1` to the size of `s2`. I don't have to keep the original pointer. I can copy `s1` to `s2` and return `s2` if that's a better way
I hope I explained what I'm after properly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two dimensional arrays are laid out in memory sequentially: row1 row2 row3 etc.

memcpy does a linear copy from one memory location to another.

So to achieve what you need:

a) Create a new array

```
Square **s3 = malloc(sizeof(s2));
```

b) Copy s2 into it

c) Copy stuff from s1, row by row into new

```
for(r = 0; r < NROWS_S1; r++)
    memcpy(s3[r], s1[r], sizeof(Square) * NCOLS_S1);
```

http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html

Comment: Is that the case when declaring it as pointers on the heap? is it a guarantee that they would be sequentially?

Comment: If you ask a piece of memory from the heap (using malloc or new) and if it will not fit into current heap, the heap pointer will be moved with brk() system call, but a block of memory returned by malloc is always continuous.

Comment: However, if you did not ask for the memory in one go. Eg you did a separate malloc for every row in your two-dimensional array, then they are NOT guaranteed to be laid out sequentially.

Comment: I did it like the one who asked this question did http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t315202-malloc-a-2d-array.html

Comment: The code for step C will still work. For step B, you need to do a deep copy. Basically use the code you used to initialize the array and combine it with memcpy from step C (using s2 instead of s1 of course)

Comment: `sizeof(s2)` will return `sizeof(Square**)`, which is *NOT* what you want.  The OP has allocated their array on the heap, so the size of the array is not available (all the compiler knows about is the pointer `Square** s2`).  This code will likely result in a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    //
} Square;

Square** s1; // 100x100, needs to resize and be like s2.
Square** s2; // 200x200

void resize_s1()
{
    // resize the outer array
    s1 = realloc(s1, sizeof(Square*)*200);
    memset(s1 + 100, 0, 100*sizeof(Square*)); // we initialize the newly allocated pointers to NULL

    for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    {
        // resize the inner array. Since we initialized the last
        // 100 pointers to null, realloc will just behave like
        // malloc for them.
        s1[i] = realloc(s1[i], 200*sizeof(Square));

        // ... and copy the new values in! You can omit this step,
        // but anything outside of the original bounds of s1 will
        // be uninitialized. All your pointers will be valid though.
        if(i >= 100)
            memcpy(s1[i] + 100, s2[i] + 100, 100*sizeof(Square));
    }
}
```

As a word of warning - I'm playing very fast and loose with realloc here. Read its man page for more details, but if you ever hit low memory conditions, bad things can happen.

Comment: There, I cleaned the answer up a bit.

Comment: but won't it overwrite the first 100 values of s1? because s2 has default values from 0 to 200? I need to keep the original and just add 100 'defaults'. also, should the final memcpy's size be 200*sizeof(Square)?

Comment: What do you mean by defaults?

Comment: the struct has a field of int a. all the squares in s2 has a starting value a=1. while in s1, they have been modified. I want the parts which have already been modified to not change, and the added parts to be with the a=1.

Comment: That's a different question entirely now.

Answer (score 1):

You've allocated your 2-D matrix on the heap, and you're using a `Square**` to access it.  This means that you've: (1) allocated the space for each element in one or more calls to `malloc`, and (2) allocated the space for all of the row pointers in a call to `malloc`.  How to proceed depends quite a lot of how you've allocated the array.

Below, I use `assert` to stress that each malloc/realloc can return NULL (indicating that it could not complete the request).  You'll probably want to handle these cases properly.

### Option 1: You allocated each row separately

You allocated the `s1` matrix like this:

```
Square** s1 = malloc(M1*sizeof(s1[0]));
for (size_t i=0; i < M1; i++)
  s1[i] = malloc(N1*sizeof(s1[i][0]));
```

In this case, you have to handle each row separately:

```
/* M1 and N1 set to size of s1 (M1 x N1) */
/* M2 and N2 set to size of s2 (M2 x N2) */

/* First, reallocate the pointers to each row */
Square** tmpRows = realloc(s1, M2*sizeof(*tmpRows));
assert( (tmpRows != NULL) && "Out of memory reallocating rows" );

s1 = tmpRows;

/* Now, reallocate each row */
for (size_t i=0; i < M1; i++) {
  Square* tmpVals = realloc(s1[i], N2*sizeof(tmpVals[0]));
  assert( (tmpVals != NULL) && "Out of memory reallocating row" );

  /* copy elements of s2 into new column */
  memcpy(tmpVals+N1, s2[i]+N1, (N2-N1)*sizeof(s1[i][0]));
  s1[i] = tmpVals;
}

/* Now, allocate each new row of s1 and copy the additional rows of s2 into s1 */
for (size_t i=M1; i < M2; i++) {
  s1[i] = malloc( N2 * sizeof(s1[i][0]) );
  assert( (s1[i] != NULL) && "Out of memory allocating new row" );
  memcpy(s1[i], s2[i], N2*sizeof(s1[i][0]));
}
```

### Option 2: You allocated each all of the rows at once

In this case, you allocated all of the rows in one big chunk, and then assigned pointers to the beginning of each row.  Like this:

```
Square** s1 = malloc(M1*sizeof(s1[0]));
s1[0] = malloc( M1*N1*sizeof(s1[0][0]) );
for(size_t i=1; i < M1; i++) 
  s1[i] = s1[i-1] + N1;
```

To resize the array (and initialize its new elements with those of s2), you should do the following:

```
/* M1 and N1 set to size of s1 (M1 x N1) */
/* M2 and N2 set to size of s2 (M2 x N2) */

/* Make a new copy of the elements of s1.  Linear layout of a 200x200 
 * matrix will be different than the linear layout of a 100x100 matrix.
 * Making a new copy makes it easier to initialize its values.
 */
Square* new_mat = malloc( M2*N2*sizeof(new_mat[0]) );
assert( (new_mat != NULL) && "Out of memory allocating new matrix" );

/* Initialize with values of s2.  Assumption: s2 is also allocated
 * as a contiguous array...
 */
memcpy(new_mat, s2[0], M2*N2*sizeof(s2[0][0]));

/* Now, reallocate the rows */
Square** tmpRows = realloc(s1, M2*sizeof(s1[0]));
assert( (tmpRows != NULL) && "Out of memory reallocating rows" );

s1 = tmpRows;
/* Copy data from old rows into new rows... */
for (size_t i=0; i < M1; i++) {
  /* rows of s1 still point to old_mat data, copy it into new_mat.
   * Each row in new_mat starts at (new_mat + N2*i)
   */
  memcpy( new_mat + N2*i, s1[i], N1*sizeof(s1[i][0]) );
}

/* Free old memory and assign new row pointers... */
free(s1[0]);
s1[0] = new_mat;
for (size_t i=1; i < M2; i++)
  s1[i] = s1[i-1] + N2;
```

Comment: `realloc` cannot return NULL. If you're going to be a stickler about memory safety, at least do it right.

Comment: @ClarkGaebel: C99 standard (well, draft 1124) 7.20.3.4 para 4: "The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be allocated."  So, yes, it **can** return NULL, and does if the request failed.